# Sending JavaScript Object QML signal parameter

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to connect a QML signal to a Qt slot with following parameter types:

in QML side:

```
signal Sig(var info)
```

in Qt side:

```
QObject::connect(topLevel, SIGNAL(Sig(QVariantMap)), &mObj, SLOT(mSlot(QVariantMap)));
```

Which gives me the following:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal QQuickWindowQmlImpl_QML_24::Sig(QVariantMap) in ...
```

So, I assume that types `var` and `QVariantMap` does not match. According to [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#qvariantlist-and-qvariantmap-to-javascript-array-and-object) document, `QVariantMap` types are converted to JavaScript objects. But I am not sure if it also does the other way around.

I have implemented an opposite type of connection(Qt signal with QVariantMap, QML handler with "Connections" element) which worked just fine. I was able to get the signal's argument as a JS object.

By the way, I have also tried the same connection with `string` argument types in my code, so I don't think that there is another unrelated mistake in my code.

How do I pass JS objects to Qt(C++) side using signal/slot mechanism? I haven't been able to find a solution. Not even an example that matches my case(signal and slot argument types), actually. Which makes me think that I am doing some sort of design mistake.

Comment: It'd be great if you could provide a [mcve] which replicates the problem.

Comment: it is not clear from the question if `toplevel` corresponds to the element in which the signal is declared, can you confirm this is the case?

Comment: @hyde I am not able to copy the code from the work machine. Please check the paragraph that starts with "By the way...". I only changed parameter types to string and QString. So I don't think it is something other than the argument types.

Comment: @hyde I have tried your suggestion with `QVariant`. Argument types hold and the connection seems OK. The slot parameter in Qt side is `QVariant(QJSValue, )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters are `QVariant`s on C++ side, so you need to do

```
QObject::connect(topLevel, SIGNAL(Sig(QVariant)), &mObj, SLOT(mSlot(QVariant)));
```

Note that you also need to change `mSlot` parameter type, because `QVariant` can't be implicitly converted to `QVariantMap`. To get the map in the slot, use `QVariant::toMap()` method, if it indeed is a map (if it isn't, this method returns empty map, and you need to do some debugging).

It works the other way around, because `QVariantMap` can be implicitly converted to `QVariant`.